# How to use Provisioning certificate for iOS build using TeamCity

Tags: ios, xcode, teamcity, provisioning-profile, xcode7.3

Right now I am using Xcode Plugin which is provided by TeamCity only.
This Plugin is working fine for Building the solution.

But when I want to create iOS application build for testing on real devices.
Every time it's giving me

> [18:07:32]Step 1/1: Xcode Project (7s)
>
> [18:07:39]CLEAN)] [BEROR]Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “95fdd2bf-0203-4f2a-8d57-9ad4d07c44f7”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
>
> [18:07:40][Step 1/1] Step Xcode Project failed

How I Can manage this provisioning profile from TeamCity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the final solution :

Provisioning profiles and certificates must be installed for the system user.

Provisioning profiles can be found at `/Users/<username>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` - copy them to `System/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` (Create folders that do not exist)

How to find the Library folder location : http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-reveal-your-library-folder-in-lion-or-mountain-lion--mac-31972

Answer (score 1):

iOS builds can be complex. Without knowing anythign else, my best guess would be you need to download the provisioning profile on the build agent via Xcode. The easiest way to do this is opening Xcode on the agent, click Xcode > Preferences and add an Apple ID of a developer/admin in your Apple Developer account - basically you need an ID that has access to said provisioning profile.

When you have added an Apple ID, double-click your team name and it will show that team's signing identities and provisioning profiles. Click Download All to pull down all of the provisioning profiles.

You may also need to install your signing identity to the same machine's keychain in order to code sign. That signing identity is specified in the provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks for Reply.
Already I did this part on Xcode.
But still my TeamCity build agent is failing. Is there any way that my TeamCity build agent can invoke that certificates and provisioning profiles while building the Code using Xcode plugin in TeamCity